# How to pattern match different ways depending on a particular input?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function:

```
closeTo61 :: Tactic
closeTo61 s P2 h d e b 
    | cs + ps < 53 = 0
    | cs + ps == 61 = 100 -- Best case
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b == 0 = 0 -- Worst case
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b == 1 = 50 -- Strong case
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b == 2 = 70 -- Very Strong case
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b >= 3 = 90 -- Extremely Strong case
        where 
            ps = scoreDom d e b
            (_,cs) = s

closeTo61 s P1 h d e b 
    | cs + ps < 53 = 0
    | cs + ps == 61 = 100
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b == 0 = 0
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b == 1 = 50
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b == 2 = 70
    | numWaysToScoreN (61 - (cs + ps)) h b >= 3 = 90
        where 
            ps = scoreDom d e b
            (cs,_) = s
```

The only reason I've done this with two bindings for each possible input of the second argument is because in the `where` block the `cs` is pattern matched differently depending on this input.

Is there a way to do this using only one binding and checking the second input inside the `where` block in order to use the correct pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the pattern match into the `where` block where you define `cs`:

```
closeTo61 s p h d e b 
   ...
   where cs = case p of P1 -> fst s; P2 -> snd s
```

If you do this a lot (and, since you defined a type for `P1` and `P2`, you might be), I would extract this logic into a more meaningful helper function:

```
component P1 (x, _) = x
component P2 (_, x) = x
```

Then you can do

```
 closeTo61 s p h d e b 
   ...
   where cs = component p s
```

Answer (score 3):

You could instead do

```
closeTo61 s p h d e b
    | cs + ps < 53 = 0
    | ...
    where
        cs = chooseByP p s
        chooseByP P1 = fst
        chooseByP P2 = snd
```

Although, since you only use `s` and `p` to determine which element of `s` to use, why have them as separate arguments here?

```
closeTo61 cs h d e b
    | ...
    where
        ps = scoreDom d e b

closeTo61' s p = closeTo61 (chooseByP p s)
```